# Emacs shell control of command output display

Tags: shell, emacs, xterm

I've just upgraded OS from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 and for some reason emacs disappeared.

On reinstalling I've just noticed that running `M-x shell` then `hg diff` produces an error message:

```
WARNING: terminal is not fully functional
-  (press RETURN)
```

I think I may have fixed this by running:

```
export TERM=xterm
```

After which I got a very colourful shell experience and no warning on running `hg diff`

However, its only displaying one page of the `hg diff` output then pausing with a `:` at a time now, previously it printed the lot without stopping.

I think this may be acceptable, if I could figure out what key allows me to print the next page of `hg diff` output, and ideally, what key would allow printing *all* remaining `hg diff` output and return me to the shell prompt.

If I hit return I get an additional line at a time, but this is a bit slow and not really ideal.

I think this is maybe a question about xterm shortcut keys? Possibly not emacs specific, but I'm not sure..

Comment: not really a programming code Q of the `if/else/endif` variety. Please delete here and repost to https://askubuntu.com or https://superuser.com. Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) before asking more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

`shell-mode` is line-buffered, meaning the input won't be sent to the underlying process until you enter `RET`.  In this case, the output should be running through a program like `less` where `RET` would give you another page instead of a single line.

So, in `shell-mode` you can use `SPC` followed by a `RET`.  In `term-mode` where the default is not line-buffered (to resemble the underlying shell as transparently as possible) a single `RET` should suffice to give you a new page.